# Random effects model for meta-analysis of rare events

Tags: meta-analysis, fixed-effects-model, rare-events

The [Cochrane Handbook](https://training.cochrane.org/handbook/current/chapter-10) states that

> incorporation of heterogeneity into an estimate of a treatment effect
> should be a secondary consideration when attempting to produce
> estimates of effects from sparse data

This has for example motivated authors of [this meta-analysis](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S2215-0366(19)30223-8) to use a fixed effects model for their analysis, because their events of interest were rare.

In general, to what extent should this recommendation be followed? If I have data from studies that I have very good reasons to think that they are heterogeneous, but that report very rare events, what type of model should I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an updated version of 'the Handbook' with a more detailed explanation (https://training.cochrane.org/handbook/current/chapter-10#section-10-4-4-3). What they're saying that the RE models in Revman can be biased and therefore to use a Peto-OR (FE model) for rare events (<1%). Others (https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/18562399/) have shown that approximate/ asymptotic methods in general are biased and exact methods are more precise for dealing with meta-analysis of rare events.

Regarding FE vs. RE in general, this Q & A might provide some additional insight ([Reporting results of fixed effect MA alongside results of random effects MA](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/270543/reporting-results-of-fixed-effect-ma-alongside-results-of-random-effects-ma)). In summary, the choice of FE or RE should be an a priori decision (when both are valid options - not particularly in this case).